# cannot access crontab with sudo after being added to /etc/sudoers list

Tags: centos, sudo, cron, crontab, sudoers

My user "craig" is in the `/etc/sudoers` file on my CentOS 5.6 VM, however when I try to access the crontab using the command below I am presented with an error message:

```
sudo crontab -e -u crmpicco-stock-dev
[sudo] password for craig:
Sorry, user craig is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/crontab -e' as root on dev.localdomain.
```

Why do I get this message as I can see in my `/etc/sudoers` file that I can access the crontab requested.

Here is the entry from my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
craig   ALL=(crmpicco-stock-dev) /usr/bin/crontab, /var/spool/cron/crmpicco-stock-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

The specification `ALL=(crmpicco-stock-dev) /usr/bin/crontab` means that on `ALL` hosts, you are allowed to run `/usr/bin/crontab` as the user `crmpicco-stock-dev`. This does not mean that `sudo` will, whenever you try to run `/usr/bin/crontab`, automatically select to do so as `crmpicco-stock-dev` - the default is still `root`, which the config disallows, and the error message gives it away: `Sorry, user craig is not allowed [...] as root`.

Try running `sudo -u crmpicco-stock-dev crontab -e`. That will tell `sudo` that you want to be `crmpicco-stock-dev` and invoke `/usr/bin/crontab`, whch should be allowed; `crontab -e` will by default try to edit the crontab of the current user - which will be `crmpicco-stock-dev`, so you don't need to specify that again.

Putting the `-u crmpicco-stock-dev` after the first non-option, `sudo` will assume it's part of the command you want to run, and ignore it. The whole line looks similar, but means something very different.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do :

```
sudo crontab -u crmpicco-stock-dev -e
```

From the man page this seem the correct order.

Best Regards

Comment: No, this produces the same error. So I don't think the order matters here. `[craig@dev53 dev_crmpicco]$ sudo crontab -u crmpicco-stock-dev -e
[sudo] password for craig:
Sorry, user craig is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/crontab -u crmpicco-stock-dev -e' as root on dev.localdomain.`

Comment: An alternative could be to run: sudo su -c "crontab -e" crmpicco-stock-dev

Comment: Same again, unfortunately. `Sorry, user craig is not allowed to execute '/bin/su -c crontab -e crmpicco-stock-dev' as root on dev.localdomain.`

Comment: Have you changed /etc/sudoers to allow craig to execute /bin/su ?

Comment: I have editedmy sudoers file with visudo to include the line `Cmnd_Alias SU = /bin/su`, there is no mention of the `craig` user in the file. Should adding the command alias line open it up for all users? After adding this line there has been no change to the problem - i'm still unable to access the `crmpicco-stock-dev` crontab with the `craig` user. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Changing `/etc/sudoers` to `craig   ALL=(ALL)       ALL` works, but it's not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are going to have to contact your system administrator to help you in debugging the problem.  I suspect that it is some type of artifact from either the setuid() or seteuid() calls in sudo and the fact that you are calling a SUID program.  I've seen this before and it is most frustrating to fix.

How I might start to fix it is by trying to put the crontab call in an executable wrapper program with no special perms itself and using sudo to call the wrapper program instead.